# community-based teams

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Source: [Evidence of UK’s child mental health crisis is stark and compelling (=The Guardian)](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2022/may/22/evidence-of-uks-child-mental-health-crisis-is-stark-and-compelling)

> The NHS is increasingly characterised by care gaps – the mismatch between needs and its ability to meet them quickly – as illustrated by the long waits for elective surgery, GP appointments, A&E treatment and ambulances to arrive. CAMHS is another case in point.
>
> It is hampered in its ability to offer fast, high-quality and appropriate care to all who need it by its longstanding lack of everything needed to run a responsive service: staff, ***community-based teams*** to keep people out of hospital and beds for those ill enough to need a spell as an inpatient.

I am not sure what community-based teams here refer to? My understanding of the last sentence is that for those with minor ailment, they can seek help from those medical teams in communities, so that they needn't go to hospitals. Therefore, hospitals and hospital beds can be reserved for the severely ill. I am not sure whether I read it right.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here? A comprehensive "definition" of "community-based teams"? (there isn't one). Fairly obviously, in the *specific* context here, a (British) local GP surgery would qualify, since they're in fact the *primary* "community-based" organisations for "keeping people out of hospital". But most people probably wouldn't class GP surgeries as community-based teams in other contexts (GPs today rarely if ever do "home visits", for example). They'll be thinking more in terms of school health services, health visiting services, district nurses, social workers, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - there is a cruel term used for people with mental health problems - a 'care-in-the-community' person. I think it arose in the 1980s following changes introduced by Margaret Thatcher's Conservative government, although the idea had been growing for at least 30 years before that. Community care policy is to maintain individuals in their own homes wherever possible, rather than provide care in a long-stay institution or residential establishment. It was seen as more humanitarian and was also thought to be cheaper.

Comment: Since the article is about child mental health services, it refers to helping _young_ people with _mental health issues_ while they are living at home, not 'people with minor ailments'.

Comment: @KateBunting So you understand "community-based" as synonymous with "in-home" care?

Comment: @TimR - I understand it in the same way that the other two commenters do.  I was simply reminding the OP that the article was about child mental health, not 'ailments' in general.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will help—as @FumbleFingers commented, it's not clear exactly what you are asking—but if part of the confusion is due to the *structure* of the English being used (i.e. as opposed to the meaning of the term "community-based teams"), then it might be helpful to emphasize that the part you are asking about is in the form of a *list*. That can be seen in the original, but it's possible to be confused by the fact that there is no [Oxford comma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) after the word "hospital". So it might be clearer if we take the original:

> [The NHS] is hampered…by its longstanding lack of…: staff, community-based teams to keep people out of hospital and beds for those ill enough to need a spell as an inpatient.

and present it instead as follows:

> [The NHS] is hampered…by its longstanding lack of…:
>
> 1. staff,
> 2. community-based teams…, and
> 3. beds…

Any remaining confusion is probably then simply down to the precise definition of "community-based teams", but as @FumbleFingers said, there really isn't such a definition. Certainly it's not absolutely clear from just the text you presented, although some of the intent can be inferred from the phrase, "to keep people out of hospital" (which, as I mentioned, would have been slightly easier to parse had it been followed by a comma).

All that said, for what it's worth, I would say that your own interpretation, about reserving hospitals for the more severely ill, is exactly right.

Answer (score -2):

**community-based** borders on euphemism; it is certainly jargon. It refers to drawing staff from the community; the unspoken aspects of the term that make it euphemistic are the notion that people from outside the community are incapable of understanding the needs of the community, and the use of "community" to refer to economically disadvantaged populations who must endure a range of issues and afflictions associated with such disadvantagement.